# Winform + TCPListener not loading properly

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, security, tcp

I've got a windows form that doesn't work until a connection with a tcpclient is made. And then it doesn't work properly(It hangs on, like freezed).

This is the code for the TCPListener:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ServerChatGUI
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Timer timer1;
    public TcpListener myList = null;

    public string EncryptionKey = GetHashedKey("Alexandros");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.17.1.241");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 
            // use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();


            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            this.Show();

            chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint + "\n");
            connection_lbl.Text = "Connected";
            connection_lbl.ForeColor = Color.Green;


            //InitTimer();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.ToString());
        }


    }

    public static string GetHashedKey(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        int cntr = 0;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            if (cntr == 1)
            {
                cntr = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
                cntr++;
            }
        }
        return hashString;
    }

    //Encrypting a string
    public static string TxtEncrypt(string inText, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inText);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return inText;
    }

    //Decrypting a string
    public static string TxtDecrypt(string cryptTxt, string key)
    {
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+");
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("\0", "");
        byte[] bytesBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptTxt);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                cryptTxt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cryptTxt;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
        chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Me:\t ");
        chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText(inMessage_txtbox.Text + "\n");


        String str = TxtEncrypt(inMessage_txtbox.Text, EncryptionKey);
        s.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));

    }

    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 200; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
        if (s.Available > 0)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[s.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            string msg = "";
            chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Other:\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                msg += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
            }
            chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText(TxtDecrypt(msg, EncryptionKey) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the code for the TCP Client (This one does work):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ChatClientGUI
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string EncryptionKey = GetHashedKey("Alexandros");
    public TcpClient tcpclnt = null;
    public bool cntrl = false;
    public Timer timer1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            chatDisplayer_txtbox.AppendText("this is the beginning of your chat\n");
            tcpclnt.Connect("172.17.1.241", 8001);
            // use the ipaddress as in the server program



            displayConnection_lbl.Text = "Connected";
            displayConnection_lbl.ForeColor = Color.Green;

            InitTimer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.ToString());
        }

    }

    public static string GetHashedKey(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        int cntr = 0;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            if (cntr == 1)
            {
                cntr = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
                cntr++;
            }
        }
        return hashString;
    }

    //Encrypting a string
    public static string TxtEncrypt(string inText, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inText);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return inText;
    }

    //Decrypting a string
    public static string TxtDecrypt(string cryptTxt, string key)
    {
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] bytesBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptTxt);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                cryptTxt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cryptTxt;
    }

    private void SendMessage_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chatDisplayer_txtbox.AppendText("Me:\t ");
        chatDisplayer_txtbox.AppendText(inMessage_txtbox.Text + "\n");

        String str = TxtEncrypt(inMessage_txtbox.Text, EncryptionKey);
        Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

        byte[] ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        cntrl = true;
    }


    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 200; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tcpclnt.Available > 0)
        {
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            byte[] bb = new byte[tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize];

            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string msg = "";
            chatDisplayer_txtbox.AppendText("Other:\t");
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                msg += Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
            }
            chatDisplayer_txtbox.AppendText(TxtDecrypt(msg, EncryptionKey) + "\n"); ;
        }
    }

}
}
```

For what i've been able to deduce, the fact that once it apears it hangs seems to be related to the timer, but that same timer works in the TCP client.

I'm really lost and I'd like to understand where is it that i've made a mistake and why.
Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: You're doing everything on the main ( UI ) thread, that's why your application freezes. Read about asynchronized oprations and threads.

Comment: I've read about async, but as I don't really understand i'm not using it. And also, it worked for the client. Why wouldn't it work for the listener?

Comment: Don't wait, don't make blocking calls like accept(), in GUI form ctors or event-handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ServerChatGUI
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static TcpListener myList = null;
    public static Socket s = null;
    public static string EncryptionKey = GetHashedKey("Alexandros");
    public static TextBox chatBox = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            chatBox = chatDisplay_txtbox;
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12");
            // use local m/c IP address, and
            // use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            s = myList.AcceptSocket();

            chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint + "\n");
            connection_lbl.Text = "Connected";
            connection_lbl.ForeColor = Color.Green;

            System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static string GetHashedKey(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        int cntr = 0;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            if (cntr == 1)
            {
                cntr = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
                cntr++;
            }
        }
        return hashString;
    }

    //Encrypting a string
    public static string TxtEncrypt(string inText, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inText);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return inText;
    }

    //Decrypting a string
    public static string TxtDecrypt(string cryptTxt, string key)
    {
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace(" ", "+");
        cryptTxt = cryptTxt.Replace("\0", "");
        byte[] bytesBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptTxt);
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
            aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
                    cStream.Close();
                }
                cryptTxt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cryptTxt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Me:\t ");
        chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText(inMessage_txtbox.Text + "\n");

        String str = TxtEncrypt(inMessage_txtbox.Text, EncryptionKey);
        s.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
        GC.Collect();
    }

    private void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        if (s.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[s.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            string msg = "";
            chatDisplay_txtbox.Invoke(new Action(() => chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText("Other:\t")));
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                msg += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
            }
            chatDisplay_txtbox.Invoke(new Action(() => chatDisplay_txtbox.AppendText(TxtDecrypt(msg, EncryptionKey) + "\n")));
            GC.Collect();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This code, works properly. The proble was in the timer.